# Can't get linux 'exec' command to work properly

Tags: linux, exec

I want to use the exec command to run a python script in the background of the current terminal session. Other posts suggest that

```
exec python myscript.py &
```

should run the script in the background. However the output of the program is still on my command line. Have I misunderstood the exec command? I just want to have the output of the script ignored or if this isn't possible, sent to a file.

I can't use nohup because I need to send the SIGHUP signal to my script. Apart from nohup, feel free to suggest other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running in the background just means you can interact with the current shell, but the stdout (and stderr) of the background process is still connected to the terminal. Redirect it somewhere else if you don't want it:

```
exec python myscript.py &>/dev/null &
```

Also, why do you need `exec`?

Comment: I can't use nohup because I need to send the SIGHUP signal to my script. Apart from nohup, feel free to suggest other solutions.

Comment: @JSStuball: `&>` redirects both stdout and stderr. Without `&`, stderr would still go to the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run command in the background you can use `nohup exec python myscript.py &` the output of the file is stored in nohup.out file